# How to Apply styles to a div if there is a specific class present in adjacent div

Tags: html, css, saas

I have below code in my sass application

```
<div class="btnGroup">
  <div class="kumar"></div>
  <div  class="pavan">
     YourName
     <div class="atlanta" href="#">Primary Action</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to apply style to `<div class="kumar"></div> .` only if there is a div with class name "Atlanta" as the child in its adjacent(sibling) div as in the above code otherwise i dont want to apply the style. How to do this in .scss file. Please let me know

Note: i have gone through all the solutions for CSS selectors as mentioned below, i didnt got any solution for my problem.
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

[Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: there is no previous nor parent selector as you found out, you need here javascript to test this . sass only compiles its files  into plain CSS and never sees the document where css is applied

Comment: Please don't repeat questions just because you don't like the answers you were given

Comment: @paulie.. u had closed the previous question and you had mnentioned "Your post has been associated with similar questions. If these questions don’t resolve your question, ask a new one."..

Comment: so i deleted the old question and created new one as suggested by you..

Comment: please also go through the question fully.. My question is not about parent or sibling salector..it is about conditionally applying CSS..